# how to change string format using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a string input as

```
s = ["123,234,435"]
```

I want output in below format:

```
s = ["123", "234", "435"]
```

How can this be done using regular expression?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I think you need list from a comma separated string. May be split on `,` should be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

What about to replace `,` with `","`

*Java*

No regex:

```
    String str = "[\"123,234,435\"]";   

    System.out.println(str.replace(",", "\", \""));
```

Output:

```
 ["123", "234", "435"]
```

**or Regex**

find: `/\,/g`

replace with `", "`

see <kbd>**[Link](http://regexr.com?375su)**</kbd>

Comment: how to do it using reg ex?

Comment: why do you need regex? make your code simple and less expensive (performance) or post actual string you work with. BTW, what lang you write?

Comment: No need for capture blocks, just replace `,` with `", "`, just like your string replace was

Answer (score 0):

This should work ( vim format since you didn't specify what program you are using )

```
%s/,/", "/g
```

Comment: Do you need to escape the `,`??

Comment: Apparently not, removed the escapes after testing it without the escaping.